# Как с помощью ajaxa запускать функцию php?

Tags: php, ajax

Есть php функция

```
function randomUsers($link){
    $query = 'select * from users order by rand()';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $guestname = $arr['username'];
    $guestfoto = $arr['img'];
    $guestold  = $arr['date'];
    $age = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $guestold)->diff(new DateTime('now'))->y;
    $guestcity = $arr['city'];
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'random'){
    randomUsers($link);
}
```

В html есть кнопка, как при нажатии запустить эту функцию с помощью ajaxa
И как мне потом в html получить переменные $guestname и т.д?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К нажатию кнопки надо привязать JavaScript функцию, отправляющую ajax-запрос на сервер. В библиотеке jQuery это делается с помощью функции [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

В запросе есть параметр url. Сервер должен при запросе этого url вызывать функцию randomUsers и вернуть ответ, содержащий необходимые переменные, например, в формате json.

При успешном получении ответа сервера будет вызвана функция, указанная в качестве параметра success функции ajax. Этой функции будет передан ответ сервера, содержащий переданные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Костыляка костыльная но по успешному окончанию функции можно в php написать 
`die(json_encode($value))` а на стороне jq указать что принимаем JSON.